# Iterating through tuples in python

Tags: python, loops, tuples

I'm having some trouble iterating through a list comprised of tuples.

It seems that the problem is with the indices in the `for` loop.

Whenever I run the program the only outcome is:

```
('joao', 300, 20)
```

Can anyone please explain to me with this is happening?

```
tuplo = [('joao', 300, 20), ('ana', 80, 15), ('patricia', 17, 90)]
def coordenadas(tuplo, name):
    for index in range(len(tuplo)):        
        if tuplo[index][0] == name:
            print(tuplo[index][0:])
        else:
            return None

coordenadas(tuplo,'joao')
coordenadas(tuplo,'ana')
coordenadas(tuplo,'patricia')
```

Comment: Try: http://www.pythontutor.com | what did you expect to happen?

Comment: What is the slice, and the letter `o`, in `[o:]` supposed to do?  The code you supply does not run (`NameError: name 'o' is not defined`).  Even if you mean zero, that slice is not useful in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I am sure you mean to use `0` instead of `o` in your slice.

`print(tuplo[indice][o:])` => `print(tuplo[indice][0:])`

Your problem is that you are using `return` this exits your function. instead you should use `continue`.

```
tuplo = [('joao',300,20),('ana',80,15),('patricia',17,90)]
def coordenadas(tuplo,nome):
    for indice in range(len(tuplo)):
        if tuplo[indice][0] == nome:
            print(tuplo[indice][0:])
        else:
            continue

coordenadas(tuplo,'joao')
coordenadas(tuplo,'ana')
coordenadas(tuplo,'patricia')
```

Output:

```
('joao', 300, 20)
('ana', 80, 15)
('patricia', 17, 90)
```

---

If I were to write this function I would do something else:

First of all, I would not use the same name for tuplo inside the function and outside. 
Secondly, I would iterate over the items in the list instead of their indices (which is the correct way to iterate in python)
Thirdly, I would optimize the function to this:

```
global_tuplo = [('joao',300,20),('ana',80,15),('patricia',17,90)]

def coordenadas(tuplo,nome):
    for tup in tuplo:
        if tup[0] == nome:
            print(tup)


coordenadas(global_tuplo, 'joao')
coordenadas(global_tuplo, 'ana')
coordenadas(global_tuplo, 'patricia')
```

Comment: if possible I'd give you another +1 for the longer explanation

Comment: Thank you for the help!
I did the return None, because that was what was specified in the exercise my teacher gave me :/
The same name was just to make easier when running... And the iteration is also as my teacher thought us to iterate through tuples :/

Comment: @MiguelLuís all functions return `None` by default. And you should (almost) never be iterating over indices in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `else` and changing `[o:]` to `[0]` makes your code work

```
tuplo = [('joao',300,20),('ana',80,15),('patricia',17,90)]
def coordenadas(tuplo,nome):
    for indice in range(len(tuplo)):  
        if tuplo[indice][0] == nome:
            print(tuplo[indice][0])

coordenadas(tuplo,'joao')
coordenadas(tuplo,'ana')
coordenadas(tuplo,'patricia')
```

If you want the name details change `tuplo[indice][0]` to `tuplo[indice]`

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
else:
    return None
```

breaks out of the `for` loop if the `if` test doesn't succeed, so if the name doesn't match the first tuple in the list no other names are tested. You don't want that!

Also, you don't need to do

```
tuplo[index][0:]
```

you can just do

```
tuplo[index]
```

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
tuplo = [
    ('joao', 300, 20),
    ('ana', 80, 15),
    ('patricia', 17, 90),
]

def coordenadas(tuplo, nome):
    for indice in range(len(tuplo)):
        if tuplo[indice][0] == nome:
            print(tuplo[indice])

coordenadas(tuplo, 'joao')
coordenadas(tuplo, 'ana')
coordenadas(tuplo, 'patricia')
```

**output**

```
('joao', 300, 20)
('ana', 80, 15)
('patricia', 17, 90)
```

BTW, if you only want to find the first matching tuple you can add a `break` or `return` statement to the end of the `if` block, like this:

```
def coordenadas(tuplo, nome):
    for indice in range(len(tuplo)):
        if tuplo[indice][0] == nome:
            print(tuplo[indice])
            break
```

---

However, there are better ways to do this task. In Python, it's better to iterate directly over the items in a collection rather than iterate indirectly via indices:

```
def coordenadas(tuplo, nome):
    for t in tuplo:
        if t[0] == nome:
            print(t)
            break
```

A more efficient way is to convert your list to a dictionary, especially if you have many tuples. For example:

```
tuplo = [
    ('joao', 300, 20),
    ('ana', 80, 15),
    ('patricia', 17, 90),
]

tuplo_dict = {t[0]: t for t in tuplo}

def coordenadas(data, nome):
    print(nome, data.get(nome))

coordenadas(tuplo_dict, 'joao')
coordenadas(tuplo_dict, 'ana')
coordenadas(tuplo_dict, 'patricia')
coordenadas(tuplo_dict, 'tom')
```

**output**

```
joao ('joao', 300, 20)
ana ('ana', 80, 15)
patricia ('patricia', 17, 90)
tom None
```

This uses a little more RAM, but it is much more efficient than the previous versions because searching for an item in a dictionary is *very* fast.